# Erro ao iniciar servidor Http no Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

Olá galera sou novo com Ruby e estou tentando criar meu primeiro projeto mas quando eu vou iniciar o servidor com o comando `rails server` eu recebo este erro:

```
João@joao-note MINGW64 ~/Documents/Desenvolvimento/Rails/Primeiro_Projeto/hello (master)
$ rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:22:inbuild': C:/Users/Joǜo/Documents/Desenvolvimento/Rails/Primeiro_Projeto/hello/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in definition'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:88:insetup'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in <top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:inrequire'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in rescue in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:inrequire'
from C:/Users/João/Documents/Desenvolvimento/Rails/Primeiro_Projeto/hello/config/boot.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:inrequire_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in <main>
```

Já instalei o bundle com o comando `bundle install`

Mas mesmo assim tenho este erro.
Alguém sabe porque?

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Abraços

Comment: Seu projeto está com o arquivo Gemfile?

Comment: Sim @LuizCarvalho esta com ele e esta na pasta do projeto. Precisa que poste aqui o arquivo? Obrigado.

Comment: Poste a estrutura do projeto. Pode usar o [tree](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm)

Comment: @LuizCarvalho oque é esse tree? Desculpa a pergunta. Eu não sei =/

Comment: Mandei o link dele ai no comentário. Ele serve para mostrar a estrutura de um diretório.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia reinstalar o ruby de uma outra forma.. já usei o railsInstaller mas não curti muito..
você pode tentar instalar por [aqui](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)(baixe tbm o devkit compativel com a versão), até a mesma versão.
Depois de baixar extraia o dev kit, acesse a pasta extraída através do terminal e rode:

```
ruby dk.rb init

ruby dk.rb install

gem install rails
```

Acesse a pasta do seu projeto pelo terminal e rode o

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu reinstalei pelo código fonte e deu tudo certo.

Obrigado a todos.